# Differentiate vertical and horizontal shapes

Tags: qgis, vectorization

I have the following shape file:
[image: Screenshot of QGIS canvas]

Each polygonal area (the lines are areas) is one feature in a single Shapefile.

Can anyone think of a simple method that can be implemented with qgis to separate the vertical lines from the horizontal ones, so that two separate shapefiles remain at the end?

Comment: Question is unclear. Each line is a separate file? What exactly do you want to achieve? Can you share sample data and add more details to your question?

Comment: Hey @Babel, sorry if its unclear. I have one shapefile. Each line is a single feature and I want to create information about each feature if its vertical or horizontal and export all verticals to one shape and all horizontals to one shapefile.

Comment: Select by azimuth, export to different files, tada.

Comment: Those are polygonal areas, correct? How would you want to sort ones that are square or circles?

Comment: @Erik great idea but unfortunately these are areas not lines :/ I changed the desciption

Comment: @bugmenot123 yes they are polygonal areas I have no clue how I would handle squares or circles. Maybe I would just accept the small lack of precision

Comment: I posted a solution that works. What do you guys think of it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Grass: v.voronoi.skeleton for "polygon to line"
2. as @Erik mentioned, use calculate the azimuth of each line (field calculator):
   "azimuth" or
   "degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)))"
3. filter expression for vertikal lines:
   "( 350 < "azimuth" or "azimuth" < 15) or (165 < "azimuth" and "azimuth" < 195)"
4. buffer to create polygonal areas again